# How to write emails from form to csv in php?

Tags: php

Hey I'm testing my form to csv program on the built in php web server, and I can't quite get it to work.  I'm trying to write email submissions from a form to a csv file with each email as a new line.

Here is my form:

```
  <form id="form" action="welcome.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Here is my welcome.php file:

```
<?php

$email = $_POST["email"];
$file = fopen("list.csv", "w");

fputcsv($file, array($email));

fclose($file);
```

Right now when I click submit nothing happens.  The text stays in the input field, and nothing is in my list.csv

Comment: Could be dangerous as people do tend to use commas in normal email text!

Comment: basic debugging: did you check if the `fopen()` succeeded? Did you check of `$_POST` contains what you think it did?

Comment: `fputcsv` expects its 2nd parameter to be an array (of that row's fields).  In your example, `$_POST["email"]` (and therefore `$email`) is *not* an array.

Comment: Looks like it's not even making it to the welcome script. Open up firebug or developer tools. Trace the route. Tail your Apache error logs. Inspect your Access logs. Are the requests even being made?

Comment: `The text stays in the input field` seems like an issue on the client-side. It should at the very least show a different page. Is welcome.php and the form in the same file?

Comment: Most likely apache (the server) does not have permission to write to list.csv. Try chmod 777 list.csv

Comment: I checked the sharing and permissions of list.csv and it is both read and write.  I have updated my code to take an array for the second parameter.  Not sure how to check the server.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, The `fputcsv()` method take array as the second argument so you should try as

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
$file = fopen("list.csv", "w");

echo fputcsv($file, array($email));

fclose($file);
?>
```

You can see the prototype of `fputcsv` method from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: The code is working might be the problem is with your access permission on list.CSV So make sure the server can access that file and you have given 'write' permission for this file.

Comment: the file has read and write permissions.  How do I make sure the server can access it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `button type="submit"` use `input type="submit"`